# Recursive (nested) grep gives "invalid character range" error

Tags: grep, osx, regular-expression

I have a file `test.xml` (shown below). 
This grep works:

```
grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml
```

Output is:

```
    <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>
```

But this fails:

```
grep "$(grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml)" test.xml
```

Output is:

```
grep: invalid character range
```

Contents of `test.xml`:

```
<note>
    <to>Jim</to>
    <from>John</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Some text</body>
    <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>
</note>
```

I have put both `grep` commands (the simple one and the nested one)
into a script with `set -x`. 
Here is an exact copy & paste of that script:

```
set -x
grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml
grep "$(grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml)" test.xml
exit 0
```

and here is its output:

```
++ grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml
    <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>
+++ grep '<appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml
++ grep '    <appointment-id internal:ref=1.2.3/>' test.xml
grep: invalid character range
++ exit 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Your (inner) `grep` produces colorized output, even though the output is not a terminal.  It may do so when the `GREP_COLOR` environment variable is set to `always`.

The control codes to do the colorization contains characters that, when you feed them into the outer `grep`, are interpreted as character ranges.

When interpreted as character ranges, the pattern is invalid.

The solution is to disable colorization of the output from `grep`, either by explicitly using `--color=never` or by setting the appropriate environment variable (`GREP_COLOR=never`).

If you set `GREP_COLOR=auto`, `grep` should only produce colorized output when writing to a terminal, as is the case for the outer `grep` in your example, but not the inner `grep`.

Comment: But then isn't understanding the grep output more difficult if the actual search patter is not highlighted if we set the environment variable to never?

Comment: @Jim I can't say that I ever had that issue. I know what I grep for and when a line is returned from the file, I know that it has matched. This seems to be enough for me at least.  If you set `GREP_COLOR=auto`, `grep` should only produce colorized output when writing directly to the terminal.  This may be better for you, possibly.